# How to create new column in Python pandas dataframe with column labels based on the content of those columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a bunch of data files from a scientific instrument that come with checksums. I've read the files into a combined pandas dataframe, but the checksum for each row is for comparison to the column label of the checksum column and is unique to each file. This results in a dataframe with O10 columns with very large strings in the column labels and column values (for the rows from the file with that column label). Now I need to combine these O10 columns into 2 columns, one for the values, and one for the headers the checksums are compared against.

Simplified Example Starting Table, CH=Checksum Header, CV=Checksum Value

| CH_A | CH_B | CH_C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| CV_A1 | NaN | NaN |
| CV_A2 | NaN | NaN |
| NaN | CV_B1 | NaN |
| NaN | NaN | CV_C1 |

Should combine to be 2 columns

| ChecksumHeaders | ChecksumValues |
| --- | --- |
| CH_A | CV_A1 |
| CH_A | CV_A2 |
| CH_B | CV_B1 |
| CH_C | CV_C1 |

The 'ChecksumValues' table was easy enough to get with df.ffill, but I'm struggling to determine a good method for creating the 'ChecksumHeaders' column. Seeing as how `'string'*1 =='string'` and `'string'*0 ==''`. I tied using a number of variations of  `np.sum([df[CH].notnull().astype(np.int)*CH for CH in ListOfHeaders])` but found that the string*int only works as a single equation and trying to do an array results in errors like:
`UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'multiply' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U9'), dtype('int32')) -> None`

So to ensure it was only 1 at a time I used nested list comprehension:
`df['ChecksumHeaders'] = [''.join([ListOfHeaders[idx]*df[CH].notnull().iloc[rowidx].astype(np.int) for idx,CH in enumerate(ListOfHeaders)]) for rowidx in np.arange(len(df))]` which works fine if you only have a handful of rows and columns to go through, but takes a long time when it needs to run through O10 columns and O100k rows. Surely there's a better way to do this, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can do:

```py
print(
    df.stack()
    .reset_index(level=1)
    .rename(columns={"level_1": "ChecksumHeaders", 0: "ChecksumValues"})
)
```

Prints:

```
  ChecksumHeaders ChecksumValues
0            CH_A          CV_A1
1            CH_A          CV_A2
2            CH_B          CV_B1
3            CH_C          CV_C1
```

Answer (score 1):

With [`pd.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) operation:

```
pd.melt(df, value_vars=df.columns, var_name='ChecksumHeaders', value_name='ChecksumValues').dropna()
```

---

```
   ChecksumHeaders ChecksumValues
0             CH_A         CV_A1 
1             CH_A         CV_A2 
6             CH_B         CV_B1 
11            CH_C         CV_C1
```

---

In case if row index matters add `ignore_index=False` option:

```
(pd.melt(df, value_vars=df.columns, var_name='ChecksumHeaders', 
 value_name='ChecksumValues', ignore_index=False).dropna())
```

---

```
  ChecksumHeaders ChecksumValues
0            CH_A         CV_A1 
1            CH_A         CV_A2 
2            CH_B         CV_B1 
3            CH_C         CV_C1
```